# Moveit & UR speed scaling: Controller is taking too long to execute trajectory

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I am using a UR robot and Moveit. I am using speed scaling to adjust the speed of the robot.
[This](https://github.com/UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver) is the UR driver that I am using and this is my controllers.yaml:

```
controller_list:
  - name: ""
    action_ns: scaled_pos_traj_controller/follow_joint_trajectory
    type: FollowJointTrajectory
    joints: [shoulder_pan_joint, shoulder_lift_joint, elbow_joint, wrist_1_joint, wrist_2_joint, wrist_3_joint]
```

Like mentioned in [this question](https://answers.ros.org/question/196586/how-do-i-disable-execution_duration_monitoring/) I added:

```
<param name="allowed_execution_duration_scaling" value="100.0"/>
```

but with a speed of 20% I still get the error:

```
Controller is taking too long to execute trajectory
```

Even though a allowed_execution_duration_scaling value of 5 should be enough for 20% of the speed.

With values over 50% I am not getting any error messages.

Do I have a wrong understanding of the function of the allowed_execution_duration_scaling?

What other ways are there to change the robot speed with moveit?

Thanks!

Daniel

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/358165/moveit-&-ur-speed-scaling:-controller-is-taking-too-long-to-execute-trajectory/) by [dschimpf](https://answers.ros.org/users/52101/dschimpf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2020-07-28

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-07-28**:
This should not be necessary, but it depends a bit on *what* exactly you are trying to do.

As a first step: please update your question to mention which driver you are using.

**Comment by [dschimpf](https://answers.ros.org/users/52101/dschimpf/) on 2020-07-28**:
I updated my question. Please let me know if any other information may be helpful. Thank you!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-07-28**:
Based on your update: this is a "know issue". MoveIt's trajectory execution manager is not aware of any scaling on the driver/robot controller side, so it will assume 100% of the joint limits are available for execution. This will cause timeouts when executing trajectories with a robot controller configured for a lower maximum scale.

I'm not aware of any work to fix this right now. Possible approaches:

- update the trajectory execution manager to be able to deal with the concept of scaling (perhaps subscribe to the appropriate topic published by the driver)
- use velocity an acceleration scaling on the MoveIt-side (ie: don't use full joint limits to parameterise trajectories)

**Comment by [dschimpf](https://answers.ros.org/users/52101/dschimpf/) on 2020-07-28**:
Because moveit is not aware of any scaling thought I could use the allowed_execution_duration_scaling. And by setting it to 5 my task would be allowed to last 5 times as long before a timeout. Which should be enough when executing it at 20% of the speed. I'll look into the other things. Thank you!

**Comment by [dschimpf](https://answers.ros.org/users/52101/dschimpf/) on 2021-03-02**:
@gvdhoorn Would I be able to send the planned cartesian trajectory with MoveIt through a different trajectory execution manager and then make use of the speed scaling? If so do you have some resources that show how to do this? Could I follow this tutorial (http://wiki.ros.org/Robots/TIAGo/Tutorials/trajectory_controller) to send the trajectory and be able to scale the speed?
My main goal is to execute a cartesian trajectory (planned with MoveIt ) and be able to change the speed during the execution. I am ok with not using the MoveIt execution manager. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For anyone that wants to do the same thing:
What I have decided to do now is changing the max_velocity in joint_limits.yaml (from moveit_config, created from setup assistant). I still need to have the set the speed scaling to 100%, but now the robot moves slower.
In rviz under planning one can also set the velocity factor (from 0 - 1). That worked for plans created in rviz, but not through a C++ file.

Second option:
Use /ur_hardware_interface/set_speed_slider topic to change speed scaling value.
Use trajectory from MoveIt and convert it from moveit_msgs::RobotTrajector to control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryGoal.

```
moveit_msgs::RobotTrajectory trajectory;
trajectory_msgs::JointTrajectory joints_combined = trajectory.joint_trajectory;
control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryGoal goal;
goal.trajectory = joints_combined;
goal.goal_time_tolerance = ros::Duration(1.0);
```

This can then be send to robot via action client and won't stop because of slow execution.

```
actionlib::SimpleActionClient<control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryAction> ac("/scaled_pos_joint_traj_controller/follow_joint_trajectory", true);
 ac.sendGoal(goal);
```

---

Originally posted by [dschimpf](https://answers.ros.org/users/52101/dschimpf/) with karma: 21 on 2020-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-03-09**:\

> Second option: Use /ur_hardware_interface/set_speed_slider topic to change speed scaling value

as long as it's clear you're *changing the position of the slider on the TP*, not setting the "speed scaling value" directly.

**Comment by [dschimpf](https://answers.ros.org/users/52101/dschimpf/) on 2021-03-09**:
Yes, from a node I am changing the position of the slider on the TP which changes the speed scaling value.